# Magento Sales > Orders > Add print action

Tags: magento, printing

I'm trying to create a print action on the magento orders page(printscreen: sbx.mujjo.com/media/images/action.png). Right now 'Print Labels' is a url to a html page. I'm trying to get it to open a .pdf instead (just like 'Print invoice'. But I can't find the right code.

The code that create the url:

```
class AquiveMedia_Orderlabel_Model_Observer {

public function add_action($observer) {
    $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
    if ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Massaction) {
       if ($block->getParentBlock() instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid) {
        $block->addItem('print_labels', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Labels'),
            'url' => $block->getUrl('orderlabel/adminhtml_orderlabel/massprint')
                 )
        );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the link already exists just use the URL for yourself. Here is how to override.

In your module's `config.xml` file,

```
<config>
    ...
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <aquivemedia_orderlabel before="Mage_Adminhtml">
                            AquiveMedia_Orderlabel_Adminhtml
                        </aquivemedia_orderlabel>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

Now you can make a controller and it will be called first.
`app/code/local/AquiveMedia/Orderlabel/controllers/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/InvoiceController.php`:

```
class AquiveMedia_Orderlabel_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_InvoiceController
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function printAction()
    {
        // this is called instead of the path "index.php/admin/sales_order_invoice/print"
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer!

I think I didn't really explain good enough. I want to open this page (orderlabel/adminhtml_orderlabel/massprint) instead of html.

So I quess that I should create an invoicecontroller but something like a labelcontroller. What are your thoughts about this. I don't have a lot of experience with things like this so If you could help I would be willing to pay you something for it!

Regards!